# Filter foreign keys in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, foreign-keys, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am using C# and DataGridView WinForms, binding to a DataTable. My DataGridView contains the following columns:

- MaterialId (read-only foreign key displaying material title)
- PricelistId (DataGridViewComboBoxCell with selectable foreign key)

Each material has specific pricelists that belong to it. This information exists in my pricelists table.

Currently When I click on the PricelistId combo, I get all the pricelists, regardless of the material they belong to. But I want to filter this according to MaterialId value. So if for example the material on the first row is steel, only steel pricelists should be displayed in the pricelist field. If the second row's material is plastic, only pricelists related to plastic should be displayed in the respective combo.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: [DataGridView Cascading/Dependent ComboBox Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487773/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you so much, this is what I needed. I'll convert it to C#, tailor it a bit to my needs and post it here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by @RezaAghaei, here is a prototype in C# tailored for my needs, also fixing an issue (currently selected item would reset).

Thanks!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataGridView _dataGridView = new DataGridView();
    private DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GenerateDataSet();
        CreateDataGridView();
    }


    private void CreateDataGridView()
    {
        var MaterialsColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        {
            DataPropertyName = "MaterialId",
            HeaderText = "Material",
            DataSource = _dataSet.Tables["Materials"],
            DisplayMember = "Name",
            ValueMember = "Id",
            Name = "MaterialColumn",
            ReadOnly = true
        };

        var PricelistsColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        {
            DataPropertyName = "PricelistId",
            HeaderText = "Pricelist",
            DataSource = _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"],
            DisplayMember = "Name",
            ValueMember = "Id",
            Name = "PricelistColumn"
        };

        _dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _dataGridView.Columns.AddRange(MaterialsColumn, PricelistsColumn);
        _dataGridView.DataSource = _dataSet.Tables["PricelistAssignments"];

        _dataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += EditingControlShowing;
        _dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        _dataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        Controls.Add(_dataGridView);
    }


    private void GenerateDataSet()
    {
        // Create tables
        _dataSet.Tables.Add("Materials");
        _dataSet.Tables["Materials"].Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        _dataSet.Tables["Materials"].Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        _dataSet.Tables.Add("Pricelists");
        _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].Columns.Add("MaterialId", typeof(int));

        _dataSet.Tables.Add("PricelistAssignments");
        _dataSet.Tables["PricelistAssignments"].Columns.Add("MaterialId", typeof(int));
        _dataSet.Tables["PricelistAssignments"].Columns.Add("PricelistId", typeof(int));

        // Populate tables
        _dataSet.Tables["Materials"].Rows.Add(1, "Steel");
        _dataSet.Tables["Materials"].Rows.Add(2, "Plastic");
        _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].Rows.Add(1, "PL Steel 1", 1);
        _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].Rows.Add(2, "PL Plastic 1", 2);
        _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].Rows.Add(3, "PL Steel 2", 1);
        _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].Rows.Add(4, "PL Plastic 2", 2);
        _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].Rows.Add(5, "PL Plastic 3", 2);
        _dataSet.Tables["PricelistAssignments"].Rows.Add(1, 3);
        _dataSet.Tables["PricelistAssignments"].Rows.Add(1, 1);
        _dataSet.Tables["PricelistAssignments"].Rows.Add(2, 4);
    }


    private void EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1) // Pricelist column
        {
            var combo = (DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
            var selectedValue = combo.SelectedValue;
            var data = _dataSet.Tables["Pricelists"].AsDataView();
            data.RowFilter = "MaterialId = " + grid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            combo.DataSource = data;
            combo.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```