# VB.NET - Datagridview combobox filter and null value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've read this post [DataGridView Cascading/Dependent ComboBox Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438171/datagridview-cascading-dependent-combobox-columns) and I've make the same project with datagridview and 2 column combobox where the second combobox is filter by selection of first combobox.
I wuold like to have a possibility do cancel selection in second combobox, if a user select for error a second combobox can clear a selection...

Here there are a code that I used:
1) first combobox is FASE
2) second combobox is SOTTOFASE

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        Dim grid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If (grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1) Then 'State column
            Dim combo = DirectCast(e.Control, DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
            If (grid.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value IsNot DBNull.Value) Then

                Dim dvStates = New DataView(MondoDBDataSet1.Tables("SOTTOFASI"), $"n_fase = '{grid.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value}'", "n_fase ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
                combo.DataSource = dvStates
                combo.ValueMember = "n_sottofase"
                combo.DisplayMember = "sottofase"

            Else
                combo.DataSource = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thanks for help!

This is an image of 3 step:

[Datagridview steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjePl.png)

SOLUTION:
I have implement event KeyUp and set cell value to "dbnull" when I press button "del"

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyUp
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Delete) Then

        Dim CellCombo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell

        If DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value <> -1 Then
            CellCombo = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1)
            CellCombo.Value = DBNull.Value

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: An image of your datagridview would help us gain more understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've load an image.. thanks